# Amazon S3 React build looking for media in wrong directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket, its called "skinmedica". It contains three projects, one of which is a react project. When I upload the react project (so, '`skinmedica/reactproject/build-files-here`') I notice S3 is looking for everything in the wrong directory. Its looking in:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/static/media/img1.png
```

When it should be looking in:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/skinmedica/reactproject/static/media/img1.png
```

Is there something I can do while running `npm run build` to fix this?
Here's the link if you'd like to check out the errors yourself. https://s3.amazonaws.com/skinmedica/lytera/index.html

Comment: Looks like you're using webpack, in which case this is set based on your webpack config (check out https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/). If you're using some sort of pre-configured solution you might want to check it's documentation to see if there's a way to specify this (e.g. create-react-app uses "homepage" in your package.json).

Comment: Just seeing this. Yes this was the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. In `package.json`, add key/value `"homepage: "."` to the top level. Days of searching... this was the answer.